# Tricky postgresql query optimization (distinct row aggregation with ordering)

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, optimization

I have a table of events that has a very similar schema and data distribution as this artificial table that can easily be generated locally:

```
CREATE TABLE events AS
WITH args AS (
    SELECT
        300 AS scale_factor, -- feel free to reduce this to speed up local testing
        1000 AS pa_count,
        1 AS l_count_min,
        29 AS l_count_rand,
        10 AS c_count,
        10 AS pr_count,
        3 AS r_count,
        '10 days'::interval AS time_range -- edit 2017-05-02: the real data set has years worth of data here, but the query time ranges stay small (a couple days)
)

SELECT
    p.c_id,
    'ABC'||lpad(p.pa_id::text, 13, '0') AS pa_id,
    'abcdefgh-'||((random()*(SELECT pr_count-1 FROM args)+1))::int AS pr_id,
    ((random()*(SELECT r_count-1 FROM args)+1))::int AS r,
    '2017-01-01Z00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone + random()*(SELECT time_range FROM args) AS t
FROM (
    SELECT
        pa_id,
        ((random()*(SELECT c_count-1 FROM args)+1))::int AS c_id,
        (random()*(SELECT l_count_rand FROM args)+(SELECT l_count_min FROM args))::int AS l_count
    FROM generate_series(1, (SELECT pa_count*scale_factor FROM args)) pa_id
) p
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT generate_series(1, p.l_count)
) l(id) ON (true);
```

Excerpt from `SELECT * FROM events`:

[image]

What I need is a query that selects all rows for a given `c_id` in a given time range of `t`, then filters them down to only include the most recent rows (by `t`) for each unique `pr_id` and `pa_id` combination, and then counts the number of `pr_id` and `r` combinations of those rows.

That's a quite a mouthful, so here are 3 SQL queries that I came up with that produce the desired results:

```
WITH query_a AS (
    SELECT
        pr_id,
        r,
        count(1) AS quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (pr_id, pa_id)
          pr_id,
          pa_id,
          r
        FROM events
        WHERE
          c_id = 5 AND
          t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00' AND
          t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
        ORDER BY pr_id, pa_id, t DESC
    ) latest
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2
    ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC
),


query_b AS (
    SELECT
        pr_id,
        r,
        count(1) AS quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT
          pr_id,
          pa_id,
          first_not_null(r ORDER BY t DESC) AS r
        FROM events
        WHERE
          c_id = 5 AND
          t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00' AND
          t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
        GROUP BY
          1,
          2
    ) latest
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2
    ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC
),

query_c AS (
    SELECT
        pr_id,
        r,
        count(1) AS quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT
          pr_id,
          pa_id,
          first_not_null(r) AS r
        FROM events
        WHERE
          c_id = 5 AND
          t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00' AND
          t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
        GROUP BY
          1,
          2
    ) latest
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2
    ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC
)
```

And here is the custom aggregate function used by `query_b` and `query_c`, as well as what I believe to be the most optimal index, settings and conditions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION first_not_null_agg(before anyelement, value anyelement) RETURNS anyelement
    LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
    AS $_$
  SELECT $1;
$_$;


CREATE AGGREGATE first_not_null(anyelement) (
    SFUNC = first_not_null_agg,
    STYPE = anyelement
);


CREATE INDEX events_idx ON events USING btree (c_id, t DESC, pr_id, pa_id, r);
VACUUM ANALYZE events;
SET work_mem='128MB';
```

My dilemma is that `query_c` outperforms `query_a` and `query_b` by a factor of > 6x, but is technically not guaranteed to produce the same result as the other queries (notice the missing `ORDER BY` in the `first_not_null` aggregate). However, in practice it seems to pick a query plan that I believe to be correct and most optimal.

Below are the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE)` outputs for all 3 queries on my local machine:

`query_a`:

```
CTE Scan on query_a  (cost=25810.77..26071.25 rows=13024 width=44) (actual time=3329.921..3329.934 rows=30 loops=1)
  Output: query_a.pr_id, query_a.r, query_a.quantity
  CTE query_a
    ->  Sort  (cost=25778.21..25810.77 rows=13024 width=23) (actual time=3329.918..3329.921 rows=30 loops=1)
          Output: events.pr_id, events.r, (count(1))
          Sort Key: (count(1)), events.r, events.pr_id DESC
          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=24757.86..24888.10 rows=13024 width=23) (actual time=3329.849..3329.892 rows=30 loops=1)
                Output: events.pr_id, events.r, count(1)
                Group Key: events.pr_id, events.r
                ->  Unique  (cost=21350.90..22478.71 rows=130237 width=40) (actual time=3168.656..3257.299 rows=116547 loops=1)
                      Output: events.pr_id, events.pa_id, events.r, events.t
                      ->  Sort  (cost=21350.90..21726.83 rows=150375 width=40) (actual time=3168.655..3209.095 rows=153795 loops=1)
                            Output: events.pr_id, events.pa_id, events.r, events.t
                            Sort Key: events.pr_id, events.pa_id, events.t DESC
                            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 18160kB
                            ->  Index Only Scan using events_idx on public.events  (cost=0.56..8420.00 rows=150375 width=40) (actual time=0.038..101.584 rows=153795 loops=1)
                                  Output: events.pr_id, events.pa_id, events.r, events.t
                                  Index Cond: ((events.c_id = 5) AND (events.t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (events.t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                  Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.316 ms
Execution time: 3331.082 ms
```

`query_b`:

```
CTE Scan on query_b  (cost=67140.75..67409.53 rows=13439 width=44) (actual time=3761.077..3761.090 rows=30 loops=1)
  Output: query_b.pr_id, query_b.r, query_b.quantity
  CTE query_b
    ->  Sort  (cost=67107.15..67140.75 rows=13439 width=23) (actual time=3761.074..3761.081 rows=30 loops=1)
          Output: events.pr_id, (first_not_null(events.r ORDER BY events.t DESC)), (count(1))
          Sort Key: (count(1)), (first_not_null(events.r ORDER BY events.t DESC)), events.pr_id DESC
          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=66051.24..66185.63 rows=13439 width=23) (actual time=3760.997..3761.049 rows=30 loops=1)
                Output: events.pr_id, (first_not_null(events.r ORDER BY events.t DESC)), count(1)
                Group Key: events.pr_id, first_not_null(events.r ORDER BY events.t DESC)
                ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=22188.98..63699.49 rows=134386 width=32) (actual time=2961.471..3671.669 rows=116547 loops=1)
                      Output: events.pr_id, events.pa_id, first_not_null(events.r ORDER BY events.t DESC)
                      Group Key: events.pr_id, events.pa_id
                      ->  Sort  (cost=22188.98..22578.94 rows=155987 width=40) (actual time=2961.436..3012.440 rows=153795 loops=1)
                            Output: events.pr_id, events.pa_id, events.r, events.t
                            Sort Key: events.pr_id, events.pa_id
                            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 18160kB
                            ->  Index Only Scan using events_idx on public.events  (cost=0.56..8734.27 rows=155987 width=40) (actual time=0.038..97.336 rows=153795 loops=1)
                                  Output: events.pr_id, events.pa_id, events.r, events.t
                                  Index Cond: ((events.c_id = 5) AND (events.t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (events.t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                  Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.385 ms
Execution time: 3761.852 ms
```

`query_c`:

```
CTE Scan on query_c  (cost=51400.06..51660.54 rows=13024 width=44) (actual time=524.382..524.395 rows=30 loops=1)
  Output: query_c.pr_id, query_c.r, query_c.quantity
  CTE query_c
    ->  Sort  (cost=51367.50..51400.06 rows=13024 width=23) (actual time=524.380..524.384 rows=30 loops=1)
          Output: events.pr_id, (first_not_null(events.r)), (count(1))
          Sort Key: (count(1)), (first_not_null(events.r)), events.pr_id DESC
          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=50347.14..50477.38 rows=13024 width=23) (actual time=524.311..524.349 rows=30 loops=1)
                Output: events.pr_id, (first_not_null(events.r)), count(1)
                Group Key: events.pr_id, first_not_null(events.r)
                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=46765.62..48067.99 rows=130237 width=32) (actual time=401.480..459.962 rows=116547 loops=1)
                      Output: events.pr_id, events.pa_id, first_not_null(events.r)
                      Group Key: events.pr_id, events.pa_id
                      ->  Index Only Scan using events_idx on public.events  (cost=0.56..8420.00 rows=150375 width=32) (actual time=0.027..109.459 rows=153795 loops=1)
                            Output: events.c_id, events.t, events.pr_id, events.pa_id, events.r
                            Index Cond: ((events.c_id = 5) AND (events.t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (events.t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                            Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.296 ms
Execution time: 525.566 ms
```

Broadly speaking, I believe that the index above should allow `query_a` and `query_b` to be executed without the Sort nodes that slow them down, but so far I've failed to convince the postgres query optimizer to do my bidding.

I'm also somewhat confused about the `t` column not being included in the Sort key for `query_b`, considering that quicksort is not stable. It seems like this could yield the wrong results.

I've verified that all 3 queries generate the same results running the following queries and verifying they produce an empty result set:

```
SELECT * FROM query_a
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM query_b;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM query_a
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM query_c;
```

I'd consider `query_a` to be the canonical query when in doubt.

I greatly appreciate any input on this. I've actually found a [terribly hacky workaround](https://github.com/felixge/pquery/raw/master/presentation/deckset.pdf) to achieve acceptable performance in my application, but this problem continues to hunt me in my sleep (and in fact vacation, which I'm currently on) ... .

FWIW, I've looked at many similar questions and answers which have guided my current thinking, but I believe there is something unique about the two column grouping (`pr_id`, `pa_id`) and having to sort by a 3rd column (`t`) that doesn't make this a duplicate question.

**Edit:** The outer queries in the example may be entirely irrelevant to the question, so feel free to ignore them if it helps.

Comment: What is the intended (natural) key for the events table? What is it supposed to mean, is it some kind of transition-probability table?

Comment: The natural key is `pa_id`. Each `pa_id` refers to "a thing" that has ~1...30 events recorded about it. `c_id` partitions the things into different groups. `pr_id` and `r` are essentially the data that is being recorded. It's not a transition-probability table, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to describe the actual business domain in more detail.

Comment: no screen shots, please update this to use text.

Comment: @EvanCarroll are you referring to the screenshot of the table I posted? I wanted to supply this as a HTML table, but couldn't figure out how to do it with the SO editor. I also think it's not a problem b/c the data in the table can be generated with the first query I supplied, so it's not like anybody would be forced to manually type out stuff from the screen shot in order to work on this question ...

Answer (score 1):

> I'd consider `query_a` to be the canonical query when in doubt.

I found a way to make `query_a` half a second fast.

Your inner query from `query_a`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pr_id, pa_id)
```

needs to go with

```
ORDER BY pr_id, pa_id, t DESC
```

especially with `pr_id` and `pa_id` listed first.
`c_id = 5` is const, but you cannot use your index `event_idx (c_id, t DESC, pr_id, pa_id, r)`, because the columns are not organized by `(pr_id, pa_id, t DESC)`, which your `ORDER BY` clause demands.
If you had an index on at least `(pr_id, pa_id, t DESC)` then the sorting does not have to happen, because the `ORDER BY` condition aligns with this index.

So here is what I did.

```
CREATE INDEX events_idx2 ON events (c_id, pr_id, pa_id, t DESC, r);
```

This index can be used by your inner query - at least in theory.
Unfortunately the query planner thinks that it's better to reduce the number of rows by using index `events_idx` with `c_id` and `x <= t < y`.
Postgres does not have index hints, so we need a different way to convince  the query planner to take the new index `events_idx2`.

One way to force the use of `events_idx2` is to make the other index more expensive.
This can be done by removing the last column `r` from `events_idx` and make it  unusable for `query_a` (at least unusable without loading the pages from the heap).

It is counter-intuitive to move the `t` column later in the index layout, because usually the first columns will be chosen for = and ranges, which `c_id` and `t` qualify well for.
However, your `ORDER BY (pr_id, pa_id, t DESC)` mandates at least this subset as-is in your index. Of course we still put the `c_id` first to reduce the rows as soon as possible.

You can still have an index on `(c_id, t DESC, pr_id, pa_id)`, if you need, but it cannot be used in `query_a`.

Here is the query plan for `query_a` with `events_idx2` used and `events_idx` deleted.
Look for `events_c_id_pr_id_pa_id_t_r_idx`, which is how PG names indices automatically, when you don't give them a name.
I like it this way, because I can see the order of the columns in the name of the index in every query plan.

```
 Sort  (cost=30076.71..30110.75 rows=13618 width=23) (actual time=426.898..426.914 rows=30 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (count(1)), events.r, events.pr_id DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=29005.43..29141.61 rows=13618 width=23) (actual time=426.820..426.859 rows=30 loops=1)
         Group Key: events.pr_id, events.r
         ->  Unique  (cost=0.56..26622.33 rows=136177 width=40) (actual time=0.037..328.828 rows=117204 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using events_c_id_pr_id_pa_id_t_r_idx on events  (cost=0.56..25830.50 rows=158366 width=40) (actual time=0.035..178.594 rows=154940 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((c_id = 5) AND (t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.201 ms
 Execution time: 427.017 ms
(11 Zeilen)
```

The planning is instantaneously and the performance is sub second, because the index matches the `ORDER BY` of the inner query.

With good performance on `query_a` there is no need for an additional function to make alternative queries `query_b` and `query_c` faster.

#### Remarks:

Somehow I could not find a primary key in your relation.
The aforementioned proposed solution works without any primary key assumption.
I still think that you have some primary key, but maybe forgot to mention it.

> The natural key is `pa_id`. Each `pa_id` refers to "a thing" that has
>   ~1...30 events recorded about it.

If `pa_id` is in relation to multiple `c_id`'s, then `pa_id` alone cannot be key.
If `pr_id` and `r` are data, then maybe `(c_id, pa_id, t)` is unique key?
Also your index `events_idx` is not created unique, but spans all columns of the relation, so you could have multiple equal rows - do you want to allow that?

If you really need both indices `events_idx` and the proposed `events_idx2`, then you will have the data stored 3 times in total (twice in indices, once on the heap).

Since this really is a tricky query optimization, I kindly ask you to at least consider adding a bounty for whoever answers your question, also since it has been sitting on SO without answer for quite some time.

**EDIT A**
I inserted another set of data using your excellently generated setup above, basically doubling the number of rows.
The dates started from '2017-01-10' this time.
All other parameters stayed the same.

Here is a partial index on the time attribute and it's query behaviour.

```
CREATE INDEX events_timerange ON events (c_id, pr_id, pa_id, t DESC, r) WHERE '2017-01-03' <= t AND t < '2017-01-06';

Sort  (cost=12510.07..12546.55 rows=14591 width=23) (actual time=361.579..361.595 rows=30 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (count(1)), events.r, events.pr_id DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=11354.99..11500.90 rows=14591 width=23) (actual time=361.503..361.543 rows=30 loops=1)
         Group Key: events.pr_id, events.r
         ->  Unique  (cost=0.55..8801.60 rows=145908 width=40) (actual time=0.026..265.084 rows=118571 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using events_timerange on events  (cost=0.55..8014.70 rows=157380 width=40) (actual time=0.024..115.265 rows=155800 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (c_id = 5)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.214 ms
 Execution time: 361.692 ms
(11 Zeilen)
```

Without the index events_timerange (that's the regular full index).

```
Sort  (cost=65431.46..65467.93 rows=14591 width=23) (actual time=472.809..472.824 rows=30 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (count(1)), events.r, events.pr_id DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=64276.38..64422.29 rows=14591 width=23) (actual time=472.732..472.776 rows=30 loops=1)
         Group Key: events.pr_id, events.r
         ->  Unique  (cost=0.56..61722.99 rows=145908 width=40) (actual time=0.024..374.392 rows=118571 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using events_c_id_pr_id_pa_id_t_r_idx on events  (cost=0.56..60936.08 rows=157380 width=40) (actual time=0.021..222.987 rows=155800 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((c_id = 5) AND (t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.171 ms
 Execution time: 472.925 ms
(11 Zeilen)
```

With the partial index the runtime is about 100ms faster, meanwhile the whole table is twice as big.
(Note: the second time around it was only 50ms faster. The advantage should grow, the more events are recorded, though, because the queries requiring the full index will become slower, as you suspect (and i agree)).
Also, on my machine, the full index is 810 MB for two inserts (create table + additional from 2017-01-10).
The partial index WHERE 2017-01-03 <= t < 2017-01-06 is only 91 MB.
Maybe you can create partial indices on a monthly or yearly basis?
Depending on what time range is queried, maybe only recent data needs to be indexed, or otherwise only old data partially?

I also tried partial indexing with `WHERE c_id = 5`, so partitioning by c_id.

```
Sort  (cost=51324.27..51361.47 rows=14880 width=23) (actual time=550.579..550.592 rows=30 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (count(1)), events.r, events.pr_id DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=50144.21..50293.01 rows=14880 width=23) (actual time=550.481..550.528 rows=30 loops=1)
         Group Key: events.pr_id, events.r
         ->  Unique  (cost=0.42..47540.21 rows=148800 width=40) (actual time=0.050..443.393 rows=118571 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using events_cid on events  (cost=0.42..46736.42 rows=160758 width=40) (actual time=0.047..269.676 rows=155800 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.366 ms
 Execution time: 550.706 ms
(11 Zeilen)
```

So partial indexing may also be a viable option.
If you get ever more data, then you may also consider partitioning, for example all rows aged two years and older into a separate table or something.
I don't think Block Range Indexes BRIN (indices) might help here, though.
If you machine is more beefy than mine, then you can just insert 10 times the amount of data and check the behaviour of the regular full index first and how it behaves on an increasing table.

Comment: Thanks for this thoughtful reply!

My concern is that by moving the `t` column later in the index, this query will perform worse over time, the more events exist.

About a bounty: Happy to add one, what do you think is appropriate? (I've never used the SO bounty system).

My real table has a `id uuid` primary key, but that's not a "natural" key AFAIK. Multiple equal rows (except for id column) are allowed to exist right now, but are very unlikely due to the way the data is collected. I don't need the `events_idx` for anything else, so I'm happy to completely replace it.

Comment: You can have an additional index on (c_id, t) if you want. The events_idx2 works, because the index is organized with t DESC and group by does not have to sort, which you can see in a shorter query plan. You have a well set up testing environment described. You can just push 10 times the rows and test the query time then. The index should prevent bad query times by construction. Also PostgreSQL has partial indexes, so you could INDEX WHERE c_id = 5, and the like. Please add any bounty you want. I'm fine with what i get. I learned a lot figuring this one out. So I am already rewarded by that :)

Comment: Ah, I think undestand now what you mean. `query_a` will only be restricted with `c_id` = 5 and then traverse the whole index leaf nodes. So if the c_id's are stable over time, then there will be more index pages to read because there are more events. Maybe one full index on all timestamps and in addition PARTIAL indexes with time ranges? The full index covers the case when a partial index does not apply due to t out of range. But i don't measure a difference for: INDEX (...) WHERE '2017-01-03' <= t AND t < '2017-01-06', which perfectly matches your `query_a`.

Comment: Please read the section starting at **EDIT A**.
Preventing the inner sort for the first GROUP BY really is the killer trick here, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the additional ideas! You're on the right track, c_ids stay pretty stable over time, but more and more events get added. The partial indexes are a cool idea, but the query ranges are chosen by the user, so things will always fall apart when trying querying across two partial indexes :(. Q: Do you agree that query_c demonstrates a correct/fast plan can exist for the index I designed? If yes, do you think it's possible to get this plan from a ambiguous query like query_a? I also agreed on preventing the inner sort! I also started a bounty ... :)

Comment: s/ambiguous query/non-ambiguous query/ in the above 

Comment: You can create both PARTIAL indices per year or month, and one FULL index, such that performance does not degrade too much.

Comment: I think that's just reducing the chance of hitting the edge case where the time range spawns two months (but it will still occur every month), but makes all queries slower in exchange. To give you some actual numbers: Our events table grows by 1-3 million records per day, so I strongly suspect an index covering a whole month will be slower than query_a and the index I designed ... :(

Comment: I had another idea to prevent a full index. There is a CAVEAT. Your query may only span a certain time range, for example `time_range = 1 day`, such that in all queries your `WHERE t1 <= t <= t2` has `t2 - t1 <= time_range`.
In this case, a FULL index is NOT NEEDED, but only OVERLAPPING PARTIAL indices. For example, you can choose partial indices spanning 5 days each, with an overlap of `time_range = 1 day` at the respective beginning and end of the overlapping indices. Partial index B starts 1 day before partial index A ends, `B.begin = A.end - time_range`. There can be NO edge case.

Comment: I'm actually lobbying for restricting the `time_range` options in the UI ... but so far without luck. If I could get stakeholders to agree on this, I could actually eagerly materialize the aggregation results for each day in a separate table using triggers. It's really the fact that the time range is variable, and that the operations don't associate/commute that are preventing ahead-of-time computation of this query : |.

Answer (score 1):

**[EDITED]**
Ok, As this depend of your data distribution here is another way to do it.

First add the following index :

`CREATE INDEX events_idx2 ON events (c_id, t DESC, pr_id, pa_id, r);`

This extract the `MAX(t)` as quick as he can, on the assumption that the sub set will be way smaller to join on the parent table. It may however probably be slower if the dataset is not that small.

```
SELECT
    e.pr_id,
    e.r,
    count(1) AS quantity
FROM events e
JOIN (
    SELECT
        pr_id,
        pa_id,
        MAX(t) last_t
    FROM events e
    WHERE
        c_id = 5 
        AND t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00' 
        AND t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
    GROUP BY 
        pr_id, 
        pa_id
) latest 
    ON (
        c_id = 5 
        AND latest.pr_id = e.pr_id
        AND latest.pa_id = e.pa_id
        AND latest.last_t = e.t
    )
GROUP BY
    e.pr_id,
    e.r
ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC
```

---

## Full Fiddle

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e319f/2)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
--PostgreSQL 9.6
--'\\' is a delimiter

-- CREATE TABLE events AS...

VACUUM  ANALYZE events;
CREATE INDEX idx_events_idx ON events (c_id, t DESC, pr_id, pa_id, r);
```

**Query 1**:

```
  -- query A
explain analyze SELECT
        pr_id,
        r,
        count(1) AS quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (pr_id, pa_id)
          pr_id,
          pa_id,
          r
        FROM events
        WHERE
          c_id = 5 AND
          t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00' AND
          t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
        ORDER BY pr_id, pa_id, t DESC
    ) latest
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2
    ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e319f/2/0)**:

```
QUERY PLAN
Sort  (cost=2170.24..2170.74 rows=200 width=15) (actual time=358.239..358.245 rows=30 loops=1)
Sort Key: (count(1)), events.r, events.pr_id
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
->  HashAggregate  (cost=2160.60..2162.60 rows=200 width=15) (actual time=358.181..358.189 rows=30 loops=1)
->  Unique  (cost=2012.69..2132.61 rows=1599 width=40) (actual time=327.345..353.750 rows=12098 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=2012.69..2052.66 rows=15990 width=40) (actual time=327.344..348.686 rows=15966 loops=1)
Sort Key: events.pr_id, events.pa_id, events.t
Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 792kB
->  Index Only Scan using idx_events_idx on events  (cost=0.42..896.20 rows=15990 width=40) (actual time=0.059..5.475 rows=15966 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((c_id = 5) AND (t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Heap Fetches: 0
Total runtime: 358.610 ms
```

**Query 2**:

```
  -- query max/JOIN
explain analyze     SELECT
        e.pr_id,
        e.r,
        count(1) AS quantity
    FROM events e
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            pr_id,
            pa_id,
            MAX(t) last_t
        FROM events e
        WHERE
            c_id = 5 
            AND t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00' 
            AND t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
        GROUP BY 
            pr_id, 
            pa_id
    ) latest 
        ON (
            c_id = 5 
            AND latest.pr_id = e.pr_id
            AND latest.pa_id = e.pa_id
            AND latest.last_t = e.t
        )
    GROUP BY
        e.pr_id,
        e.r
    ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e319f/2/1)**:

```
QUERY PLAN
Sort  (cost=4153.31..4153.32 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=68.398..68.402 rows=30 loops=1)
Sort Key: (count(1)), e.r, e.pr_id
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
->  HashAggregate  (cost=4153.29..4153.30 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=68.363..68.371 rows=30 loops=1)
->  Merge Join  (cost=1133.62..4153.29 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=35.083..64.154 rows=12098 loops=1)
Merge Cond: ((e.t = (max(e_1.t))) AND (e.pr_id = e_1.pr_id))
Join Filter: (e.pa_id = e_1.pa_id)
->  Index Only Scan Backward using idx_events_idx on events e  (cost=0.42..2739.72 rows=53674 width=40) (actual time=0.010..8.073 rows=26661 loops=1)
Index Cond: (c_id = 5)
Heap Fetches: 0
->  Sort  (cost=1133.19..1137.19 rows=1599 width=36) (actual time=29.778..32.885 rows=12098 loops=1)
Sort Key: (max(e_1.t)), e_1.pr_id
Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 640kB
->  HashAggregate  (cost=1016.12..1032.11 rows=1599 width=36) (actual time=12.731..16.738 rows=12098 loops=1)
->  Index Only Scan using idx_events_idx on events e_1  (cost=0.42..896.20 rows=15990 width=36) (actual time=0.029..5.084 rows=15966 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((c_id = 5) AND (t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Heap Fetches: 0
Total runtime: 68.736 ms
```

**Query 3**:

```
DROP INDEX idx_events_idx
CREATE INDEX idx_events_flutter ON events (c_id, pr_id, pa_id, t DESC, r)
```

**Query 5**:

```
  -- query A + index by flutter
explain analyze SELECT
        pr_id,
        r,
        count(1) AS quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (pr_id, pa_id)
          pr_id,
          pa_id,
          r
        FROM events
        WHERE
          c_id = 5 AND
          t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00' AND
          t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
        ORDER BY pr_id, pa_id, t DESC
    ) latest
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2
    ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e319f/2/4)**:

```
QUERY PLAN
Sort  (cost=2744.82..2745.32 rows=200 width=15) (actual time=20.915..20.916 rows=30 loops=1)
Sort Key: (count(1)), events.r, events.pr_id
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
->  HashAggregate  (cost=2735.18..2737.18 rows=200 width=15) (actual time=20.883..20.892 rows=30 loops=1)
->  Unique  (cost=0.42..2707.20 rows=1599 width=40) (actual time=0.037..16.488 rows=12098 loops=1)
->  Index Only Scan using idx_events_flutter on events  (cost=0.42..2627.25 rows=15990 width=40) (actual time=0.036..10.893 rows=15966 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((c_id = 5) AND (t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Heap Fetches: 0
Total runtime: 20.964 ms
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the data distribution caveat. I've experimented in this direction before without good results, and unfortunately your query seems to be no exception: https://gist.github.com/felixge/5c6c0da3055238b1be2e75487fdb727d (2x slower than my already-too-slow query_a)

Comment: @FelixGeisendörfer Oh sh*t !! I forgot the most important line on(c_id=5. please check again, this give me a strange cost (without the `vacuum analyze` it was really small, around 300) but a better runtime.

Comment: I get ~3400ms for query 1 and ~970ms for query 2. I get the same plan for query 2, so I wonder what kind of hellish fast machine you've got :). Anyway, your answer seems to be the best I've got so far, and the bounty was about to expire, so I awarded it to you. I'm still leaving the question open for a few more days, b/c I'd love to find a query that is as fast as query_c ..., but perhaps that's impossible with the current query planner.

Comment: That's strange. I get similar results on my machine for these two queries, yet still about only 500 ms for the query in my answer. You did run `VACUUM ANALYZE events` after creating the other index on `(c_id, pr_id, pa_id, t DESC, r)`, did you? What is the runtime of my query on your machine then, please?

Comment: @flutter the answer(s) you provided were very good as well. The reason I prefer Blag's answer is because it keeps `t` early in the index and doesn't require dynamic index management or invasive schema changes. I still think there is no "correct" answer that produces a plan as good as `query_c`, but I didn't want to let the bounty expire, which means the karma points are lost.

Answer (score 0):

Just two different methods(YMMV):

---

```
-- using a window finction to find the record with the most recent t::
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT pr_id, r, count(1) AS quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (pr_id, pa_id)
          pr_id, pa_id,
                 first_value(r) OVER www AS r
                 -- last_value(r) OVER www AS r
        FROM events
        WHERE c_id = 5
         AND t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00'
         AND t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
        WINDOW www AS (PARTITION BY pr_id, pa_id ORDER BY t DESC)

        ORDER BY 1, 2, t DESC
    ) sss
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC
        ;

-- Avoiding the window function; find the MAX via NOT EXISTS() ::

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT pr_id, r, count(1) AS quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (pr_id, pa_id)
          pr_id, pa_id, r
        FROM events e
        WHERE c_id = 5
         AND t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00'
         AND t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
         AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM events nx
                WHERE nx.c_id = 5 AND nx.pr_id =e.pr_id AND nx.pa_id =e.pa_id
                AND nx.t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00'
                AND nx.t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
                AND nx.t > e.t
                )
    ) sss
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC
        ;
```

---

Note: the `DISTINCT ON` can be omitted from the second query, the results are already unique.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried your queries. Your first query using a window functions seems to give similar performance as my queries a and b. Your second query is ~2x slower than my query a and b. Unfortunately all of them are still much slower than my query c.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use a standard `ROW_NUMBER()` function with a matching index instead of Postgres-specific `DISTINCT ON` to find the "latest" rows.

**Index**

```
CREATE INDEX ix_events ON events USING btree (c_id, pa_id, pr_id, t DESC, r);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_RN
AS
(
    SELECT
        pa_id
        ,pr_id
        ,r
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c_id, pa_id, pr_id ORDER BY t DESC) AS rn
    FROM events
    WHERE
        c_id = 5
        AND t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00'
        AND t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
)
SELECT
    pr_id
    ,r
    ,COUNT(*) AS quantity
FROM CTE_RN
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY 
    pr_id
    ,r
ORDER BY quantity, r, pr_id DESC
;
```

I don't have Postgres at hand, so I'm using http://rextester.com for testing. I set the `scale_factor` to 30 in the data generation script, otherwise it takes too long for rextester. I'm getting the following query plan. The time component should be ignored, but you can see that there are no intermediate sorts, only the sort for the final `ORDER BY`. See http://rextester.com/GUFXY36037

Please try this query on your hardware and your data. It would be interesting to see how it compares to your query. I noticed that optimizer doesn't choose this index if the table has the index that you defined. If you see the same on your server, please try to drop or disable other indexes to get the plan that I got.

```
1   Sort  (cost=158.07..158.08 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=81.445..81.448 rows=30 loops=1)
2     Output: cte_rn.pr_id, cte_rn.r, (count(*))
3     Sort Key: (count(*)), cte_rn.r, cte_rn.pr_id DESC
4     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
5     CTE cte_rn
6       ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.42..157.78 rows=12 width=88) (actual time=0.204..56.215 rows=15130 loops=1)
7             Output: events.pa_id, events.pr_id, events.r, row_number() OVER (?), events.t, events.c_id
8             ->  Index Only Scan using ix_events3 on public.events  (cost=0.42..157.51 rows=12 width=80) (actual time=0.184..28.688 rows=15130 loops=1)
9                   Output: events.c_id, events.pa_id, events.pr_id, events.t, events.r
10                  Index Cond: ((events.c_id = 5) AND (events.t >= '2017-01-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (events.t < '2017-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
11                  Heap Fetches: 15130
12    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.28..0.29 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=81.363..81.402 rows=30 loops=1)
13          Output: cte_rn.pr_id, cte_rn.r, count(*)
14          Group Key: cte_rn.pr_id, cte_rn.r
15          ->  CTE Scan on cte_rn  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.214..72.841 rows=11491 loops=1)
16                Output: cte_rn.pa_id, cte_rn.pr_id, cte_rn.r, cte_rn.rn
17                Filter: (cte_rn.rn = 1)
18                Rows Removed by Filter: 3639
19  Planning time: 0.452 ms
20  Execution time: 83.234 ms
```

---

There is one more optimisation you could do that relies on the external knowledge of your data.

If you can guarantee that each pair of `pa_id, pr_id` has values for each, say, day, then you can safely reduce the user-defined range of `t` to just one day.

This will reduce the number of rows that engine reads and sorts if user usually specifies range of `t` longer than 1 day.

---

If you can't provide this kind of guarantee in your data for all values, but you still know that usually all `pa_id, pr_id` are close to each other (by `t`) and user usually provides a wide range for `t`, you can run a preliminary query to narrow down the range of `t` for the main query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    MIN(MaxT) AS StartT
    MAX(MaxT) AS EndT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            pa_id
            ,pr_id
            ,MAX(t) AS MaxT
        FROM events
        WHERE
            c_id = 5
            AND t >= '2017-01-03Z00:00:00'
            AND t < '2017-01-06Z00:00:00'
        GROUP BY
            pa_id
            ,pr_id
    ) AS T
```

And then use the found `StartT,EndT` in the main query hoping that new range would be much narrower than original defined by the user.

The query above doesn't have to sort rows, so it should be fast. The main query has to sort rows, but there will be less rows to sort, so overall run-time may be better.

Comment: Thanks! This performs well on the artificial data set I posted, but unfortunately the real data set is covering a much larger time range t. Therefor any index that doesn't include the column t early on will degrade in performance as the events table grows over time. I made an edit to clarify this in the question text earlier today. If I get a chance I'll also try to adjust the dummy data generation query to reflect this.

Comment: I see. Well, `top-n-per-group` can be done in two ways - `row_number()` or `lateral join`. How many different combinations of `(pa_id, pr_id)` for a given `c_id` (and not limiting `t`) do you have? If this number is not too large, then lateral join may be faster. What is the result of this query for you real data?:  `WITH
 CTE
 AS
 (
  SELECT DISTINCT
   pa_id
   ,pr_id
  FROM events
  WHERE
   c_id = 5
 )
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM CTE;
`

Comment: The number is pretty large. Depending on c_id, it can be easily several million.

Comment: @FelixGeisendörfer, I'm afraid there is not much you can do. If you say, that the table has a lot of dates and you select only a small range, then your index is better. But, when you select rows within a range of dates, these rows are sorted by `t`. But you need them to re-sort by `(pa_id, pr_id)` to get the latest row for each combination of this pair. I don't see how you can avoid this sort. The fact that your query C returned correct result is purely by chance and you should not rely on it.

Comment: @FelixGeisendörfer, in other words, I don't think you can build an index that would put rows in the order that would suit both selecting a subset with constant `c_id` and range of `t` AND then picking latest `pa_id, pr_id`.  **IF** the possible range of `t` is not arbitrary, say, always a day or a week or a month (any day/week/month), then it is possible (by kind of pre-partitioning by these possible ranges of `t`).

Comment: I disagree. I think query_c has a correct *and* performant query plan. I just have no guarantees that the optimizer will always pick this plan. The trick in query_c's plan is to simply iterate the index in order (which implies `t DESC`) and then use a hash map to store the first result for the key `(pa_id, pr_id)`. This avoids the need for a sort, is correct, and is fast. Does this make sense?

Comment: @FelixGeisendörfer, I see. Yes, I agree that there exists an algorithm that can produce correct result with one pass of the index without intermediate sort. I just don't see how to force SQL engine to follow it. Most likely, a custom aggregate function would help, it just has to be not so simple as you wrote. It has to work correctly when rows are fed into it in any order. As far as I understand, SQL engine doesn't guarantee the order of processing the rows for the `GROUP BY`. For example, SQL Server can do it in several parallel threads. So, your best bet is custom aggregate function...

Comment: @FelixGeisendörfer, ... Inside the custom aggregate function you'd maintain a dictionary of all pairs `pa_id, pr_id` with the largest `t` and corresponding `r`. It could be a hash or b-tree dictionary and for each new row you'd check if the current `pa_id, pr_id` is already in the dictionary and update its `t` and `r` if needed. So, SQL engine would not do explicit sort, but your code must produce correct result with any order of rows.

Comment: I tried creating such a custom agg before using hstore/json, but unfortunately it was pretty slow. However, SQL actually does have a way to tell the planner about the order to use for feeding stuff into the aggregate of a GROUP BY, and I'm using it in `query_b`: `first_not_null(r ORDER BY t DESC) AS r`. The problem is just that the optimizer doesn't realize that this doesn't require an additional sort node, b/c the index is already being scanned in the right order ... 

Comment: If you use `first_not_null(r ORDER BY t DESC)`, then you ask engine to sort the rows. In this case there is overhead of sorting, but function can be simple. If you use `first_not_null(r)`, then engine is free to feed rows into the function in any order and your code has to handle it. Yes, apparently, engine is not smart enough to avoid explicit extra sort in the first case.

Comment: By the way, did you try `first_not_null(r ORDER BY c_id, t DESC)` or `first_not_null(r ORDER BY c_id, t DESC, pa_id, pr_id)` to match the index exactly?

Comment: Yes, I tried (and just double-checked again). At this point I'm almost convinced it's going to take a patch for the query planner to solve this problem correctly ...

Comment: @FelixGeisendörfer, added one idea for possible optimisation to the answer. Its usefulness depends on your data distribution and values of parameters that user specifies.

Comment: Thanks. The second option (narrowing down the time range) doesn't work given the way the data is distributed (i.e. the resulting new time range will almost always be identical or almost identical to the one selected by the user). I didn't understand your first suggestion (There is one more optimisation ...) TBH. Can you give an example for that?

Comment: @FelixGeisendörfer, the first suggestion is just a more specific variant of the second. The second suggestion is to run an extra query to determine the possibly narrow range of `t`. The first suggestion is to know in advance based on the general knowledge of your data what range of `t` you can safely use instead of the one that is supplied by the user (to know this narrow safe range of `t` without running the extra query, that is). Anyway,  you said that there is no room for such "cheating".

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the data is distributed too "tightly" to make use of such an optimization. But thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

So I've taken a little bit of a tack and tried moving your grouping and distinct data into their owns tables, so that we can leverage multiple table indexes.  Note that this solution only works if you have control over the way data gets inserted into the database, i.e. you can change the data source application.  If not, alas this is moot.

In practice, instead of inserting into the `events` table immediately, you would first check if the relational `date` and `prpa` exist in their relevant tables.  If not, create them.  Then get their `id`s and use that for your insert statement to the `events` table.

Before I start, I was generating a 10x increase in performance on query_c over query_a, and my final result for the rewritten query_a is about a 4x performance.  If that's not good enough, feel free to switch off.

---

Given the initial data seeding queries you gave in the first instance, I calculated the following benchmarks:

```
query_a: 5228.518 ms
query_b: 5708.962 ms
query_c: 538.329 ms
```

So, about a 10x increase in performance, give or take.

I'm going to alter the data that's generated in `events`, and this alteration takes quite a while.  You would not need to do this in practice, as your `INSERT`s to the tables would be covered already.

For my optimisation, the first step is to create a table that houses dates and then transfer the data over, and relate back to it in the `events` table, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
    id SERIAL,
    year_part INTEGER NOT NULL,
    month_part INTEGER NOT NULL,
    day_part INTEGER NOT NULL
);
-- Total runtime: 8.281 ms

INSERT INTO dates(year_part, month_part, day_part) SELECT DISTINCT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t), EXTRACT(DAY FROM t)
FROM events;
-- Total runtime: 12802.900 ms

CREATE INDEX dates_ymd ON dates USING btree(year_part, month_part, day_part);
-- Total runtime: 13.750 ms

ALTER TABLE events ADD COLUMN date_id INTEGER;
-- Total runtime: 2.468ms

UPDATE events SET date_id = dates.id
FROM dates
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t) = dates.year_part
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t) = dates.month_part
AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM T) = dates.day_part
;
-- Total runtime: 388024.520 ms
```

Next, we do the same, but with the key pair (`pr_id`, `pa_id`), which doesn't reduce the cardinality too much, but when we're talking large sets it can help with memory usage and swapping in and out:

```
CREATE TABLE prpa (
    id SERIAL,
    pr_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    pa_id TEXT NOT NULL
);
-- Total runtime: 5.451 ms

CREATE INDEX events_prpa ON events USING btree(pr_id, pa_id);
-- Total runtime: 218,908.894 ms

INSERT INTO prpa(pr_id, pa_id) SELECT DISTINCT pr_id, pa_id FROM events;
-- Total runtime: 5566.760 ms

CREATE INDEX prpa_idx ON prpa USING btree(pr_id, pa_id);
-- Total runtime: 84185.057 ms

ALTER TABLE events ADD COLUMN prpa_id INTEGER;
-- Total runtime: 2.067 ms

UPDATE events SET prpa_id = prpa.id
FROM prpa
WHERE events.pr_id = prpa.pr_id
AND events.pa_id = prpa.pa_id;
-- Total runtime: 757915.192

DROP INDEX events_prpa;
-- Total runtime: 1041.556 ms
```

Finally, let's get rid of the old indexes and the now defunct columns, and then vacuum up the new tables:

```
DROP INDEX events_idx;
-- Total runtime: 1139.508 ms

ALTER TABLE events
    DROP COLUMN pr_id,
    DROP COLUMN pa_id
;
-- Total runtime: 5.376 ms

VACUUM ANALYSE prpa;
-- Total runtime: 1030.142

VACUUM ANALYSE dates;
-- Total runtime: 6652.151
```

So we now have the following tables:

```
events (c_id, r, t, prpa_id, date_id)
dates (id, year_part, month_part, day_part)
prpa (id, pr_id, pa_id)
```

Let's toss on an index now, pushing `t DESC` to the end where it belongs, which we can do now because we're filtering results on `dates` before `ORDER`ing, which cuts down the need for `t DESC` to be so prominent in the index:

```
CREATE INDEX events_idx_new ON events USING btree (c_id, date_id, prpa_id, t DESC);
-- Total runtime: 27697.795
VACUUM ANALYSE events;
```

Now we rewrite the query, (using a table to store intermediary results - I find this works well with large datasets) and awaaaaaay we go!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_results;

SELECT DISTINCT ON (prpa_id)
    prpa_id,
    r
INTO TEMPORARY temp_results
FROM events
INNER JOIN dates
    ON dates.id = events.date_id
WHERE c_id = 5
AND dates.year_part BETWEEN 2017 AND 2017
AND dates.month_part BETWEEN 1 AND 1
AND dates.day_part BETWEEN 3 AND 5
ORDER BY prpa_id, t DESC;

SELECT
    prpa.pr_id,
    r,
    count(1) AS quantity
FROM temp_results
INNER JOIN prpa ON prpa.id = temp_results.prpa_id
GROUP BY
    1,
    2
ORDER BY 3, 2, 1 DESC;
-- Total runtime: 1233.281 ms
```

So, not a 10x increase in performance, but 4x which is still alright.

---

This solution is a combination of a couple of techniques I have found work well with large datasets and with date ranges.  Even if it's not good enough for your purposes, there might be some gems in here you can repurpose throughout your career.

---

EDIT:

**EXPLAIN ANALYSE on SELECT INTO query:**

```
Unique  (cost=171839.95..172360.53 rows=51332 width=16) (actual time=819.385..857.777 rows=117471 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=171839.95..172100.24 rows=104117 width=16) (actual time=819.382..836.924 rows=155202 loops=1)
        Sort Key: events.prpa_id, events.t
        Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 3944kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=14340.24..163162.92 rows=104117 width=16) (actual time=126.929..673.293 rows=155202 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (events.date_id = dates.id)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events  (cost=14338.97..160168.28 rows=520585 width=20) (actual time=126.572..575.852 rows=516503 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (c_id = 5)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=29610
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_idx2  (cost=0.00..14208.82 rows=520585 width=0) (actual time=118.769..118.769 rows=516503 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (c_id = 5)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.25..1.25 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.326..0.326 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on dates  (cost=0.00..1.25 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.320..0.323 rows=3 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((year_part >= 2017) AND (year_part <= 2017) AND (month_part >= 1) AND (month_part <= 1) AND (day_part >= 3) AND (day_part <= 5))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 7
Planning time: 3.091 ms
Execution time: 913.543 ms
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYSE on SELECT query:**
*(Note: I had to alter the first query to select into an actual table, not temporary table, on order to get the query plan for this one.  AFAIK EXPLAIN ANALYSE only works on single queries)*

```
Sort  (cost=89590.66..89595.66 rows=2000 width=15) (actual time=1248.535..1248.537 rows=30 loops=1)
  Sort Key: (count(1)), temp_results.r, prpa.pr_id
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=89461.00..89481.00 rows=2000 width=15) (actual time=1248.460..1248.468 rows=30 loops=1)
        Group Key: prpa.pr_id, temp_results.r
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=73821.20..88626.40 rows=111280 width=15) (actual time=798.861..1213.494 rows=117471 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (temp_results.prpa_id = prpa.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on temp_results  (cost=0.00..1632.80 rows=111280 width=8) (actual time=0.024..17.401 rows=117471 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=36958.31..36958.31 rows=2120631 width=15) (actual time=798.484..798.484 rows=2120631 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 16384  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 3129kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on prpa  (cost=0.00..36958.31 rows=2120631 width=15) (actual time=0.126..350.664 rows=2120631 loops=1)
Planning time: 1.073 ms
Execution time: 1248.660 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Can you show the query plan for your final query? If I'm understanding your optimizations correctly, your essentially just making the sort faster by reducing the width per row, but fundamentally the query plan stays the same?

Comment: Just added the query plans, sorry for the delay, had a busy weekend